# How could import css atribute by id/class name to another css file?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have two html files index.html and imported.html, in jquery I can load html  element, but my question is, how could I import from index.css file #preview id for that imported  element to another file which be linked with imported.html file?

This is my index.html file

```css
#preview {
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #2C2C2C;
}

.list {
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #2C2C2C;
}

.container {
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #2C2C2C;
}
```

```html
<div id="preview">
<ul>
 <li>About</li>
 <li>Pricing</li>
 <li>Contact</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

This is my imported.html file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="import"></div> 

<script>
$("#import").load("index.html #preview");
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In general you would link all CSS everywhere so the browser only needs to cache the CSS once. Dynamically loading exact selectors out of a CSS file could be done with some programming and tinkering. But why would that be neccessary?

Comment: Actually, I'am developing an program which simplify me to create front-end for custom apps through designing them by input the parameters (like width, height, color, etc.) and in background I should obtain the code in self files dynamically. I've tried with `blob` but it's a pretty static.

Answer (score 1):

To import the CSS styles for the `#preview` element from the `index.html` file to the `imported.html` file, you need to link the index.css file in the `imported.html` file, as the CSS styles are defined in that file.

Here is how you can do it:

Add a link to the index.css file in the head section of imported.html file:

```html
<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
```

Modify the `#preview` CSS selector in the index.css file to include the `#import` selector, which is the parent element of the `#preview` element in the `imported.html` file:

```css
#import #preview {
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #2C2C2C;
}
```

By doing this, the #preview element loaded from the `index.html` file will inherit the CSS styles defined in the `index.css` file, when it is displayed inside the `#import` element in the `imported.html` file.

Note that, since the `#import` element is created dynamically by the jQuery load method, you need to make sure that the index.css file is loaded before the `#preview` element is inserted into the `#import` element.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but what I actually need is that if I have more than one css id/classes defined in index.css file. How could I import one or more between them from index.css to imported.html? :)